# How to make .exe of Python program which uses PyMongo

Tags: python-2.7, pymongo, py2exe

I want make a .exe for my python program using py2exe

#### setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe

    setup(console=['first.py'])
```

#### first.py

```
print "hello"
```

Then I run this command:

> python setup.py py2exe

first.exe is successfully created in my dist folder.

Now I want to make program that used PyMongo. (I already installed PyMongo, and this program runs well independently)

#### first.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
    client = MongoClient()

    db = client['configdb']

    x = db.Model.find_one()

    print x
```

and again run

> python setup.py py2exe

But when I run first.exe I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "first.py", line 1, in <module>
      File "pymongo\__init__.pyc", line 80, in <module>
      File "pymongo\connection.pyc", line 39, in <module>
      File "pymongo\mongo_client.pyc", line 45, in <module>
      File "pymongo\pool.pyc", line 22, in <module>
      File "pymongo\thread_util.pyc", line 28, in <module>
      File "gevent\coros.pyc", line 5, in <module>
      File "gevent\lock.pyc", line 5, in <module>
      File "gevent\_semaphore.pyc", line 12, in <module>
      File "gevent\_semaphore.pyc", line 5, in __load
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path'
```

I am a beginner with py2exe. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

just change my setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    console = [{'script': "fisrt.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

and works fine now.